# Gloss command and spaces

Tags: spacing, linguistics, linguex, cgloss4e

What is wrong with my `\coolgl{}{}` *gloss* command (a clone of `cgloss4e`'s `\twosent`, and therefore, having brace-delimited arguments and being `\hfill`-compatible), which produces those unwanted spaces in the output, while `\gll`, as intended, ignores them?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolglossaux}{mmmmm}{%
    \setlength{\glossglue}{#1pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}%
    \renewcommand{\eachwordtwo}{\rule[-#2ex]{0pt}{0pt}#3}%
    \getwords(\lineone,\eachwordone)#4 \\%
    \getwords(\linetwo,\eachwordtwo)#5 \\%
    \loop\lastword{\eachwordone}{\lineone}{\wordone}%
    \lastword{\eachwordtwo}{\linetwo}{\wordtwo}%
    \global\setbox\gline=\hbox{%
        \unhbox\gline\hskip\glossglue\vtop{%
            \box\wordone\nointerlineskip\box\wordtwo%
        }%
    }%
    \testdone%
    \ifnotdone%
    \repeat%
    {\hskip -\glossglue}\unhbox\gline%
}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolgl}{O{}mm}
{
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { coolgl } { #1 }
    \coolgl:VVVnn
    \coolgl_glue
    \coolgl_space
    \coolgl_style
    { #2 }
    { #3 }
    \group_end:
}
\keys_define:nn { coolgl }
{
    glue.tl_set:N = \coolgl_glue,
    space.tl_set:N = \coolgl_space,
    style.tl_set:N = \coolgl_style,
    glue.initial:n = 1,
    space.initial:n = 1.2,
    style.initial:n = \small,
}

\cs_set_eq:NN \coolgl:nnnnn \coolglossaux

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \coolgl:nnnnn { VVV }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    
\ex.
    \a. \gll    lorsqu'\kern0.01em il est~venu\\
                when he came\\
    \b. \gll    un trompe- la- mort\\
                a deceives-\kern0.01em the-\kern0.01em death\\
    
\ex.
    \a. \coolgl{lorsqu'\kern0.01em il est~venu}{%
                when he came}%
    \b. \coolgl{un trompe- la- mort}{%
                a deceives-\kern0.01em the-\kern0.01em death}%
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AlanMunn Hi Alan, what is it that you edited?

Comment: Just the tags: removed `gb4e` and added `linguistics`.

Comment: If you click on the "Edited xxx days ago" link above the editor's name you can see exactly what they did.  Substantive (non-tag) edits will always generate a notification directly to you.

Comment: @AlanMunn and you got no idea why I have those spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons for the differences in your two output examples.

Both stem from your initial settings definition:

```latex
\keys_define:nn { coolgl }
{
    glue.tl_set:N = \coolgl_glue,
    space.tl_set:N = \coolgl_space,
    style.tl_set:N = \coolgl_style,
    glue.initial:n = 1,             % Here, you're explicitly setting an additional 1mm of glue
    space.initial:n = 1.2,
    style.initial:n = \small,       % Here, you're changing the text size of the second line.
}
```

Both of these combine to make the fragment alignments different between the two output. If you change them to

`glue.initial:n = 0,` and `style.initial:n = \normalsize,`

then your fragments will be identical (at least to my eye).

I'm not extremely familiar with LaTeX 3 syntax, so I can't necessarily recommend a more targeted change to the macro definition itself.

Comment: The whole point in using this command is to change the font size. So you are right, nothing is wrong, it's just that \twosent is not intended to have a different font size for the gloss. It acts as if the gloss was big, does not take the smaller size into account. (The glue value has only marginal impact.)